# Using chars, created by a scanner

Tags: java, methods, char

I'm trying to make a basic text game in Java. I decided just to make a game off of the console because that's the only way I know how. I'm trying to use chars to see if what the user typed contains the letter h at position 0, it worked fine when I tried it in the main method, but it's not working when I call it as a separate method.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;



    public class testing
    {

static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Wanna start the game?");
    System.out.println("1. Start");
    System.out.println("2. Quit");
    int ans = kb.nextInt();

    if(ans == 1)
    {
        levelOne();
    }

    else
        System.out.println("Quitting");
}

public static void levelOne()
{
    System.out.println("Type something");
    char letter = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if(letter == 'h')
    {
        System.out.println("contains h");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("does not contain h");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `nextInt` doesnt consume any non-numeric input you need to consume the newline characters passed by the method before `nextLine` is invoked

```
kb.nextLine(); // added
char letter = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Comment: Right It depends on the contract of the program. **OP is not getting any exception** otherwise there is `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` caught.

Answer (score 0):

remove spaces first then get the character

```
char letter = kb.nextLine().trim().charAt(0);
```

---

input `1 hello`

notice space before `hello`

Output:

```
Wanna start the game?
1. Start
2. Quit
1  hello
Type something
  hello
does not contain h
```